# Get private key of smart contract through remix

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

When I deploy a contract on to an eth network through remix, is there a way I can export that contract's private key out of remix?

Comment: Contracts do not have private keys. Are you referring to the private key of the account that deployed the contract?

Comment: Oh ok I was kind of confused. If other people send other tokens into a contract a function or selfdestruct() can be used to get it out right

Comment: Contracts can have private keys, and it would function like any other account (e.g. you'd be able to send funds from the account). Deploying a contract does not give you the private key for the contract address however. What you're likely looking for is [contract ownership](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/access#Ownable).

Comment: Contracts can have private keys _associated_ with them, but they cannot have private keys. Ownership of a contract simply maps a public key to administrative functions ona  contract, but does not mean the contract has a private key.